# Borderline off-topic (development version)

Tags: discussion

In my eyes [Remove microphone noise ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353657/remove-microphone-noise-ubuntu-13-10) although about 13.10 (due in 10 days...) might not be about a bug per se - and so be a borderline question.

What is your opinion: close it or leave it open?

Comment: The one problem I see here is that this "noise" issue happened *after* an upgrade.  Because of that, I think we have to tread very carefully in how we handle this.  Since it's an upgraded system, not a clean install or anything, we can't rule out that this could be a bug in some software that was introduced in 13.10.  At this point, i'm split evenly between leaving this as a valid question and marking it as something that should be reported as a bug...

Answer (score 6):

It was my belief, and the way that previous similar questions were treated, was that once the development version released its last RC version (Beta version in the case of 13.10), questions regarding the development version could be worked on since they were very close to the final release. Not many changes come into play at the end of the release and the actual changes that have any or most of the impact are before the RC.

So questions regarding 13.10 right now (and of course using 13.10 with the latest beta status) can be posted here. The only exceptions are questions that sound like bugs, or are found in the bug reports in launchpad, which will simply get closed because they are bugs.

I do not see anything wrong with question about [Remove microphone noise ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353657/remove-microphone-noise-ubuntu-13-10)

In fact, a good answer would be to play around with the microphone volume control in the Sound Settings. Some mics create static when they are too high or too low. This varies depending on the mic. This answer would apply even for the released version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to set a precedent, so I won't say leave it alone since it's so close and might not be a bug, but you take my point (I will be opening a bug -- contributing to bug heat on a bug and ranting -- the day 13.10 stable hits and they still haven't fixed the broken volume slider on x64, but not a question).